# Import fs in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I know this seems like a duplicate question but none of the answers I've found works:

In my `.ts` file:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'; // error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
// OR
import fs from 'fs'; // error:
// import fs from 'fs';
//        ^^
// SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

// OR

import {fs} from 'fs'; // error: module '"fs"' has no exported member 'fs'.ts(2305)


const data: [string, number] = [['one', 1],['two',2]];
function modifyThis(data: any) {
    return  data.map((element: any) => {
        element[1] = 0;
        return element;
    });
}
fs.writeFileSync('./data.txt', modifyThis(data), 'utf8');
```

I do have `"@types/node": "^12.0.0"` in my `package.json` and I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I execute the file with `ts-node`, `node` and code runner extension but it still doesn't work. I installed `ts-node` globally.

> Update:

Output of `$ts-node`:

```sh
$ ts-node modData.ts 
/.../modData.ts:1
import * as fs from 'fs';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Module.m._compile (....nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:814:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (....nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:817:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at main (....nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:226:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (....nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:485:3)
```

> Update: `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you get those errors? What commands do you run?

Comment: I used `node` and `ts-node` and also tried with a code runner extension.

Comment: `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token *` --- this cannot be reported by ts-node. Can you please re-run it with `ts-node` (only) one more time and provide the _actual_ error messages.

Comment: I've updated my question above.

Comment: In your case `import { fs } from 'fs';` should be `import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';` and `fs.writeFileSync(...` just `writeFileSync(...`. Though, `import fs from 'fs';` should work.

Comment: I think it should but it just doesn't.

Comment: Provide your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Thank you. I've added my tsconfig file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the issue:
I need to install `@types/node` package outside of the `react` app with:

```sh
$ yarn add @types/node
```

So the project looks like this:

```sh
.
├── client
│   └── package.json
└── package.json
```

Answer (score 7):

`import * as fs from 'fs';`

I used the statement in my project, and it was fine.

Maybe check for **tsconfig.json** file?

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs",
     ...
     /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "types": [
        "node",
        "vue-types",
    ], 
 },
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried `"module": "commonjs"` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How about "types" ?

Comment: It returns this error:
`
/.../.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
client/src/data/modData.ts(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.
`